# Loading variables in bash from another file

Tags: bash, workflow

I build some ROMs and other software for various Android devices and to make it easier for me, I use bash based scripts.
Here's an example from my TWRP build script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Variables
export TW_DEVICE_VERSION="0"
export BRANCH="android-5.1"

# Don't touch this
VERSION=$( grep "TW_MAIN_VERSION_STR" bootable/recovery/variables.h -m 1 | cut -d \" -f2 )-${TW_DEVICE_VERSION}

# Acer Liquid Z500 specific TWRP build configuration
export BRAND="acer"
export DEVICE="acer_Z500"

git clone https://github.com/liquidporting/android_device_${BRAND}_${DEVICE}.git -b ${BRANCH} device/${BRAND}/${DEVICE}
. build/envsetup.sh
lunch omni_${DEVICE}-eng
mka recoveryimage > twrp_${DEVICE}.log
cd out/target/product/${DEVICE}
if [ -f "recovery.img" ]
then
  mv recovery.img twrp-${VERSION}-${DEVICE}.img
else
  echo ""
  echo "*******************************************************************************"
  echo "Something went wrong during the build process, try checking your device tree."
  echo "After that, run the script again and see if you messed up something new or not."
  echo "*******************************************************************************"
  echo ""
fi

if [ -f "twrp-${VERSION}-${DEVICE}.img" ]
then
  megarm /Root/LPAD/TWRP/twrp-${VERSION}-${DEVICE}.img
  megarm /Root/LPAD/TWRP/twrp_${DEVICE}.log
  megaput --no-progress --path /Root/LPAD/TWRP twrp-${VERSION}-${DEVICE}.img
  megaput --no-progress --path /Root/LPAD/TWRP ../../../../twrp_${DEVICE}.log
fi

if [ -f "twrp-${VERSION}-${DEVICE}.img" ]
then
  cd ../../../..
  rm twrp_${DEVICE}.log
  make clean
  cd device
  rm -rf ${BRAND}
  cd ..
else
  rm twrp_${DEVICE}.log
  make clean
  cd device
  rm -rf ${BRAND}
  cd ..
  echo ""
  echo "**************************************************************"
  echo "The build process of TWRP Recovery failed for device ${DEVICE}"
  echo "**************************************************************"
  echo ""
  exit
fi

# Lenovo A328 specific TWRP build configuration
export BRAND="lenovo"
export DEVICE="A328"

git clone https://github.com/liquidporting/android_device_${BRAND}_${DEVICE}.git -b ${BRANCH} device/${BRAND}/${DEVICE}
. build/envsetup.sh
lunch omni_${DEVICE}-eng
mka recoveryimage > twrp_${DEVICE}.log
cd out/target/product/${DEVICE}
if [ -f "recovery.img" ]
then
  mv recovery.img twrp-${VERSION}-${DEVICE}.img
else
  echo ""
  echo "*******************************************************************************"
  echo "Something went wrong during the build process, try checking your device tree."
  echo "After that, run the script again and see if you messed up something new or not."
  echo "*******************************************************************************"
  echo ""
fi

if [ -f "twrp-${VERSION}-${DEVICE}.img" ]
then
  megarm /Root/LPAD/TWRP/twrp-${VERSION}-${DEVICE}.img
  megarm /Root/LPAD/TWRP/twrp_${DEVICE}.log
  megaput --no-progress --path /Root/LPAD/TWRP twrp-${VERSION}-${DEVICE}.img
  megaput --no-progress --path /Root/LPAD/TWRP ../../../../twrp_${DEVICE}.log
fi

if [ -f "twrp-${VERSION}-${DEVICE}.img" ]
then
  cd ../../../..
  rm twrp_${DEVICE}.log
  make clean
  cd device
  rm -rf ${BRAND}
  cd ..
else
  rm twrp_${DEVICE}.log
  make clean
  cd device
  rm -rf ${BRAND}
  cd ..
  echo ""
  echo "**************************************************************"
  echo "The build process of TWRP Recovery failed for device ${DEVICE}"
  echo "**************************************************************"
  echo ""
  exit
fi
```

Is possible to have a separated bash script containing build instructions and another one containing set of variables?

I Mean something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export TW_DEVICE_VERSION="0"
export BRANCH="android-5.1"

VERSION=$( grep "TW_MAIN_VERSION_STR" bootable/recovery/variables.h -m 1 | cut -d \" -f2 )-${TW_DEVICE_VERSION}

export BRAND="acer"
export DEVICE="acer_Z500"

export BRAND="lenovo"
export DEVICE="A328"

export BRAND="doogee"
export DEVICE="X5"
```

But after each device specific configuration I need it to launch the bash script containing the build instructions.

Comment: the line `. build/envsetup.sh` is already doing that. Look inside of `envsetup.sh` and you'll see similar commands (and maybe some logic controlling what gets set). Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is very much feasible and it is a good thing to do as well.

Put your configuration in a file, say, tw_config.sh.  Then, invoke the configuration script this way:

```
source /path/to/tw_config.sh
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  # couldn't load config
  # your logic here - makes sense to exit
fi
```

If tw_config.sh is in your PATH, you can simply say:

```
source tw_config.sh
```